# Quick way to show that inclusion is a local property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

I have encountered a problem which requires me to prove that ideal inclusion is a local property. That is to say, suppose $S,T \subset R$. Show that $S \subset   T \Leftrightarrow SR_P \subset TR_P$ for every prime ideal $P \subset R$.

This is rather an elementary exercise but I think it would be tedious to start with definition and prove the if and only if statement. I was wondering if there is an extremely easy and fast way to show this statement? Since I know a proposition saying that being injective or surjective as Noetherian module is a local property. The proof will be one line for Noetherian ring if we just let the injective map be inclusion. However, it is not always true for general rings. Are there any famous propositions we can use to JUST finish this proof in several sentences, or we must prove this statement from definition?

Comment: Why do you think it's not true for general rings ? I think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One implication is easy. For the harder one, suppose $S \not \subset T$. Fix an element $x \in S \setminus T$. Show that the set of all ideals of $R$ that contain $T$ and do not contain $x$ satisfies the condition for Zorn's lemma, so it has a maximal element. Show that such a maximal element $P$ is a prime ideal in $R$, and $SR_P \not \subset TR_P$.

Comment: It's well known that any proper ideal is contained into a maximal ideal.

Comment: @user26857 Many thanks to you and mathguy! Also, you have marked this as duplicated. Can you tell me what the duplicated question is? I would like to delete this question if it is duplicated. It is a shame to ask the same question but I did search on site to see whether there are similar questions.

Comment: Oops. The approach is exactly the same. The search result does not come up since the phrasing is so different. Thank you so much for stilling answering! I will delete my question several minutes later.